# Change multiple field types simultaneously in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a table (it was imported from Excel) that has a wide variety of automatically identified/assigned types (int, float, decimal, etc).  There are about 160 columns...and i want to standardize them.  I know that to change the field type i use ALTER TABLE and the CHANGE command...but you have to specify the column name...and i really don't want to have to do this individually for every column.  I tried something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Table_Name` CHANGE * * DECIMAL( 7, 4 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

but that did not work.  To make matters slightly more complicated...there is actually one field which is the primary key `StateName` that is not numeric (the values are like TX,VA,FL,NY)...and do i need to leave it alone.

In short, i am looking for something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `Table_Name` CHANGE * * DECIMAL( 7, 4 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL EXCEPT WHERE Column='StateName'
```

I just made up that syntax...i know it is nowhere close.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...based on the "answer" from OMG Ponies and assuming that there really is not a way to do this within MySQL...i wrote the following PHP script which accomplished the complete job in less than 1 second...

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `Table_Name`";
$result = @mysql_query($sql, $db);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ColumnName = $row[0];
    if($ColumnName!='StateName'){
        $UpdateSql = "ALTER TABLE `Table_Name` CHANGE `$ColumnName` `$ColumnName` DECIMAL( 7, 4 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ";
        @mysql_query($UpdateSql, $db);
    }
}
```

Hopefully it helps someone else someday.

Comment: As I said, SQL (not just MySQL) doesn't make this easy for you because data model changes are not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The pure SQL answer to this would be:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name]
MODIFY [col1] float,
MODIFY [col2] varchar(255) null
```

and so on...